# Directory.Delete runs into IOException

Tags: c#

I have created a shell script in C# that deletes Windows home folders on the server. The home folders are given by a text-file. The script loops thru the folders and deletes them. I have two log files a "success"-log and a "error"-log.

The deleting part looks like:

```
if (Directory.Exists(serverShare + "\\" + user))
{
       try
       {
               Directory.Delete(serverShare + "\\" + user, true);
               successLog.WriteLine(serverShare + "\\" + user + " --- deleted");
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
               errorLog.WriteLine(serverShare + "\\" + user + " --- Error: {0}", ex.ToString());
       }
}
else
{
      errorLog.WriteLine(serverShare + "\\" + user + " -- Errror: Directory not exists!");
}
```

Now I run into an exception:

> "System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file because it
>   is being used by another process. directory.delete pictures
>   documents".

The folder was not in use (the users who access it, works no longer in the company), so no another process can access it.

The exception occurs with folders `my documents\my music`, `my documents\my pictures`. So it could be do something with special Windows folders?

The other folders are deleted. So the script "works". Also no problems in local environment.

Comment: These error messages are misleading since often, the "another process" is in fact your own process. Are you in any way accessing these directories/files in any other piece of your code? If so, check whether the object(s) need to be/are being disposed.

Comment: Probably it's permissions issue, try and check that the folders you trying to delete can be edited by the user that "runs" the script.

Comment: It can also be something like an antivirus product

Comment: No, I don't access these directories/files. I just create the log files and then delete the folder like my printed code.

Comment: There are no Antivirus active. When I delete the folder manual (with the same User as the application runs), it works, but I have to confirm another message "this folder is shared with other people".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem. Some (system) folders have Archive or ReadOnly flags. It seems the Directory.Delete (with recursive subfolder deletion) can't delete these folders. So you have to remove these attributes first.
Removing mehtod:

```
    public static void ClearAttributes(string currentDir)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(currentDir))
        {
            File.SetAttributes(currentDir, FileAttributes.Normal);

            string[] subDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(currentDir);
            foreach (string dir in subDirs)
            {
                ClearAttributes(dir);
            }

            string[] files = files = Directory.GetFiles(currentDir);
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                File.SetAttributes(file, FileAttributes.Normal);
            }    
        }
    }
```

Then, before Directory.Delete run this method.

```
ClearAttributes(serverShare + "\\" + user);
Directory.Delete(serverShare + "\\" + user, true);
```

So it works fine and all folders are deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Can you manually delete the folder ?

You can use this `Process explorer` to get the locking file name.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-sg/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Or you can put

```
GC.Collect(); 
Directory.Delete(serverShare + "\\" + user, true);
```

Comment: Don't GC.Collect without knowing what it does, it's a cargo-cult to sprinkle it everywhere

Comment: Yes, manually delete works. But then I have to confirm another message "this folder is shared with other people".

Comment: I agree with your comment @Julien, but the process explorer suggestion is a good one. Scott Hanselman has a [good post and short video](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToUseProcessMonitorAndProcessExplorer.aspx) on using this tool to identify issues. Could be handy in the OPs instance to determine exactly what is causing the issue.

Comment: I don't know how the process explorer should help. When I manually delete the folder it works. So that should sy me: it has no process who lock it? Think I wrong?